# Hoodie - Update a CouchDB document (Node.js)

Tags: node.js, couchdb, stripe-payments, hoodie

I'm handling charges and customers' subscriptions with Stripe, and I want to use these handlings as a Hoodie plugin.

Payments and customer's registrations and subscriptions appear normally in Stripe Dashboard, but what I want to do is update my _users database in CouchDB, to make sure customer's information are saved somewhere.
What I want to do is updating the `stripeCustomerId` field in `org.couchdb.user:user/bill` document, from my `_users` database which creates when logging with Hoodie. And if it is possible, to create this field if it does not exist.

In hoodie-plugin's document, the update function seems pretty ambiguous to me.

```
// update a document in db
db.update(type, id, changed_attrs, callback)
```

I assume that `type` is the one which is mentioned in CouchDB's document, or the one we specify when we add a document with `db.add(type, attrs, callback)` for example.

`id` seems to be the doc id in couchdb. In my case it is `org.couchdb.user:user/bill`. But I'm not sure that it is this id I'm supposed to pass in my update function.

I assume that `changed_attrs` is a Javascript object with updated or new attributes in it, but here again I have my doubts.

So I tried this in my `worker.js`:

```
function handleCustomersCreate(originDb, task) {
    var customer = {
      card: task.card
    };
    if (task.plan) {
      customer.plan = task.plan;
    }

    stripe.customers.create(customer, function(error, response) {
      var db = hoodie.database(originDb);
      var o = {
        id: 'bill',
        stripeCustomerId: 'updatedId'

      };

      hoodie.database('_users').update('user', 'bill', o, function(error) {
        console.log('Error when updating');
        addPaymentCallback(error, originDb, task);
      });


      db.add('customers.create', {
        id: task.id,
        stripeType: 'customers.create',
        response: response,

      }, function(error) {
        addPaymentCallback(error, originDb, task);
      });
    });
  }
```

And between other messages, I got this error log:

```
TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON
```

And my file is not updated : `stripeCustomerId` field stays `null`.
I tried to `JSON.stringify` my `o` object, but It doesn't change a thing.

I hope than some of you is better informed than I am on this `db.update` function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I decided to join the Hoodie official IRC channel, and they solved my problem quickly.

Actually user.docs need an extra API, and to update them you have to use `hoodie.account` instead of `hoodie.database(name)`

The full syntax is:

```
hoodie.account.update('user', user.id, changedAttrs, callback)
```

where `user.id` is actually the account name set in Hoodie sign-up form, and `changedAttrs` an actual JS object as I thought.

Kudos to gr2m for the fix; ;)